# App's tmp folder size is too large; Many CFNetworkDownload.tmp

Tags: ios, swift

I found that my app storage space suddenly became very large.
Among them, there are about **2GB CFNetworkDownloadxxx.tmp** files in the tmp folder.
How these files are generated. Users are very complaining about this

Comment: This might be because NSURLSession or URLSession repeatedly was terminated and didn't have the time to clean the temp files. Check for situations where your app is going to background or terminated (or any other reason that would make URLSession abruptly stop working).

Comment: @EricAya Thank you for reply. I don't have any ideas about this. I use Alamofire to manage my network requests.